# Android - how can I create inapp products without making the app live?

Tags: android

I am reading instructions here:
http://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/test-iab-app.html

and it says to upload your app (which I did) and then I would be able to create billing items for it.  But I do not see a way to create the items for users to purchase.  Could someone please list the steps to do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: I am using the "old" / "current" version of the Developer Console, not the new version.

1. From the main page of the Developer Console, click "In-app Products"[image: screenshot showing location of In-app products link]
2. Click the "Add in-app product" button
3. Fill out necessary fields

I have not tried this on an unpublished app, so I'm not sure the steps differ prior to initial release of an app.